# Probability that second of $20$ watches is broken given $2$ are broken and after discarding first based on $80\%$-correct expert advice?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The problem goes this way. There are $20$ watches, $2$ of which are broken. And there is an expert who can say if the watch is broken. But his verdict is only correct with probability $0.8$ - in both cases, if the watch is broken and if it is not. So, then I choose one watch, show it to the expert and he says: it's broken. I choose then another watch of these $20$. What is the probability that this second watch is broken? Thanks in advance.

PS. I dont really understand how this information can help, but let it be. My math background: PhD, but it is 20 years ago, so I'm not an active mathematician anymore. The source of the problem: a student who i know. What I tried: naturally, Bayes theorem. But I still cannot solve it.

PPS. I found the solution. It goes without Bayes but with the law of total probability. Its rather technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use Bayes' Theorem for this (along with the Law of Total Probability.)

Let $B_i$ be the event that the $i^{\text{th}}$ watch is Broken, and let $R_i$ be the event that the expert Reports that the $i^{\text{th}}$ watch is broken.  We want to find
$$
P(B_2 \vert R_1) = \frac{P(R_1\vert B_2)P(B_2)}{P(R_1)}
$$
$$
= \frac{P(R_1\vert B_2)P(B_2)}{P(R_1\vert B_2)P(B_2) + {P(R_1\vert B_2^c)P(B_2^c)}}.
$$
Certainly
$$
P(B_2) = \left(\frac{2}{20}\right)
$$
and
$$
P(B_2^c) = \left(\frac{18}{20}\right).
$$
It remains to calculate $P(R_1\vert B_2)$ and $P(R_1\vert B_2^c)$.

Part I: To find $P(R_1\vert B_2)$, let us simply assume that $B_2$ is true.  So for now, we assume $B_2$, and calculate $P(R_1)$ under this assumption.  Since the second watch is broken, we know that of the $19$ other watches, exactly $1$ is broken.  Now
$$
P(R_1) = P(R_1 \vert B_1) P(B_1) + P(R_1\vert B_1^c) P(B_1^c)
$$
$$
= (0.8) \left(\frac{1}{19}\right) + (0.2) \left(\frac{18}{19}\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{4.4}{19}.
$$

But this was calculated under the condition that $B_2$ is true.  Thus we have really shown that
$$
P(R_1\vert B_2) = \frac{4.4}{19}.
$$

Part II: To calculate $P(R_1\vert B_2^c)$, we simply assume that $B_2$ is false.
Under this assumption,
$$
P(R_1) = P(R_1 \vert B_1) P(B_1) + P(R_1\vert B_1^c) P(B_1^c)
$$
$$
= (0.8) \left(\frac{2}{19}\right) + (0.2) \left(\frac{17}{19}\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{5}{19}.
$$
Because this was calculated under the assumption that $B_2$ is false, we have really shown that
$$
P(R_1\vert B_2^c) = \frac{5}{19}.
$$
Collecting our results together, we find that
$$
P(B_2\vert R_1) = \frac{\frac{8.8}{380}}{\frac{8.8}{380} + \frac{90}{380}} = \frac{22}{247}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $B_1$ denote the event that the first watch is broken and let $B_2$ denote the event that the second watch is broken.

To be found is $P(B_2)$ and we have:$$P(B_2)=P(B_2|B_1)P(B_1)+P(B_2|B_1^c)P(B_1^c)=\frac1{19}P(B_1)+\frac2{19}(1-P(B_1))=$$$$\frac2{19}-\frac1{19}P(B_1)$$
So from here it is enough to find $P(B_1)$.

Event $B_1$ can also be recognized as  the event that the expert is correct in his judgement so that $P(B_1)=0.8=\frac45$.

So our final outcome is:$$P(B_2)=\frac2{19}-\frac1{19}\frac45=\frac6{95}$$

---

**Edit**:

There is a flaw in the approach above.

The statement that event $B_1$ coincides with the event of correctness of the expert is false. Also see the comments on this question.

An approach without this flaw is:

Let $T$ denote the event that the expert is correct in his judgment.

Then $T$ and $B_1$ are independent which follows from $P(T|B_1)=P(T|B_1^c)$. Moreover it is evident that $T$ and $B_2$ are independent.

The event that the expert tells us that the first watch is broke can now be recognized as: $TB_1\cup T^cB_1^c$
and to be found is:$$P(B_2|TB_1\cup T^cB_1^c)=\frac{P(TB_1B_2)+P(T^cB_1^cB_2)}{P(TB_1)+P(T^cB_1^c)}=$$$$\frac{P(T)P(B_1)P(B_2|B_1)+P(T^c)P(B_1^c)P(B_2|B_1^c)}{P(T)P(B_1)+P(T^c)P(B_1^c)}=$$$$\frac{\frac45\frac1{10}\frac1{19}+\frac15\frac9{10}\frac2{19}}{\frac45\frac1{10}+\frac15\frac9{10}}=\frac{22}{247}\sim0.089$$

Comment: "Event B1 can also be recognized as the event that the expert is correct in his judgement" - no, its completely wrong. And the answer is wrong also.

Comment: I am willing to believe that but can you tell me what's wrong? If the expert made a correct judgement then the first watch is broken. Conversely if the first watch is broken then the expert made a correct judgement. Which of the two directions is incorrect? Are they both incorrect?

Comment: See my answer where I show that the probability that the expert makes a correct judgement is 9/13. So its not the same event that the watch is broken

Comment: "If the expert made a correct judgement then the first watch is broken." This is wrong. The expert can make a correct judgement abot the watch that is NOT broken. He can make correct judgements in both ways.

Comment: Thank you. At the moment I am working with an app that does not allow me to delete (so I will do that later). I did feel uncomfortable about my answer and had doubts on publishing. Nice problem though.

Comment: Not a problem. Thank You. :)

Comment: I think you've fallen into the "trap" that this question sets. Define $A_1$ as the event that watch 1 is actually broken, and $E_1$ as the event that the expert says that watch 1 is broken. At first blush, the question seems like it's saying that $P(A_1 | E_1) = 0.8$. But if we read carefully, I think we find that the question is actually saying that $P(E_1 | A_1) = P(\neg E_1 | \neg A_1) = 0.8$, but it's not immediately saying what $P(A_1 | E_1)$ is. Your answer assumes (falsely, I think) that $P(A_1 | E_1) = 0.8$.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 I have edited my answer and will not delete. Especially the first part illustrates nicely how easy it is to make an error on this.

Comment: @TannerSwett I indeed made an essential mistake. I have added an approach that avoids it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of the solution that does not uses the set fromalism (which is not at all denied!) but uses an intuitive approach.

(I must say it is a corrected version : the first one  was erroneous)

This 2-steps problem can be considered as equivalent to the choice, in the second step, between

- an urn $U_1$ containing 1 Broken (Black) and 18 Working (White) watches [for which the probability of drawing a B watch is $p_1=1/19$]
- an urn $U_2$ containing 2 B and 17 W balls [for which the probability of drawing a B watch is $p_2=2/19$]

Let us first consider the case where we have no information about what has happened in the first step ; in this context, the probability of having a B watch in the secound step would be :
$$\underbrace{\dfrac{2}{20}}_{w_1} \times \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{19}}_{p_1} \ \  + \ \ \ \underbrace{\dfrac{18}{20}}_{w_2} \times \underbrace{\dfrac{2}{19}}_{p_2}\tag{1}$$

The "weights" $w_k$ sum up to $1$.

Now, how are modified these weights with the verdict of the expert ? They become resp.

$$w_1=\dfrac{2}{20} \times \dfrac{4}{5} \ \text{and} \ w_2=\dfrac{18}{20} \times \dfrac{1}{5}$$

We must take care of the fact that the sum $w_1$ and $w_2$ is not $1$ ; we have to normalize these weights by dividing them by their sum $\dfrac{26}{100}$:

$$w'_1=\dfrac{8}{26} \ \text{and} \ w'_2=\dfrac{18}{26}$$

Instead of (1), we have now:

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{8}{26}}_{w'_1} \times \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{19}}_{p_1} \ \  + \ \ \ \underbrace{\dfrac{18}{26}}_{w'_2} \times \underbrace{\dfrac{2}{19}}_{p_2}=\dfrac{44}{494}=\dfrac{22}{247} \approx 0.0891$$

Comment: No, the answer is wrong. The correct answer is 225/247.

Comment: Intuitively, it is impossible to have an answer close to 1: there are very few broken watches...

Comment: Yes, you are right. 225/247 is for the complementary event. So its 22/247

Comment: Now the gaps between our two results is small... How to explain it ?

Comment: Its not a surprise, probabilites are quite small numbers and their differences can be small by chance. :)

Comment: I suppose so. But it doesnt impact P(second watch broken| expert says the first is broken) that we are looking for.

Comment: Your w1 is exactly the probability that the expert says "the watch is broken". But I don't understand why You multiply it with 1/19 in the next step. By the way, I don't really know what You mean with "weights", I don't know any weights in probability theory.

Comment: The probability to draw a red ball is either 1/19 (case of choice of urn $U_1$) or $2/19$ (other case), "weighed" resp by (indeed) the probability $w_1$ that the expert has said "the watch is brocken" or the complementary probability $w_2$ (the "weight" is nothing more than a probability). "Weight functions occur frequently in statistics and analysis, and are closely related to the concept of a measure" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function))

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is as this.
Let's $A_1$, $A_2$ be the events "first (second) watch is NOT broken".
Let's $B_1$ be the event "expert says the watch is broken".
Then we know $P(B_1|A_1^c)=P(B_1^c|A_1)=0.8$.

What we are looking for is $P(A_2|B_1)$. So, we need $P(B_1)$ and $P(A_2\cap B_1)$.
It is: $P(B_1)=P(B_1|A_1^c)P(A_1^c)+P(B_1^c|A_1)P(A_1)=13/50$.

$P(A_2\cap B_1)$ is not so easy:
$P(B_1∩A_2)=P(B_1∩A_1∩A_2)+P(B1∩A_1^c ∩ A_2) =P(B_1∣A_1\cap A_2)P(A_1∩A_2)+P(B_1∣A_1^c\cap A_2)P(A_1^c ∩ A_2)=
P ( B_1  ∣ A_1  ) P(A_1∩A_2)   + P ( B_1  ∣ A_1^c  ) P(A_1^c ∩ A_2)$ and now we know all the parts.
In the end we have $P(A_2\cap B_1)=9/38$ and $P(A_2|B_1)=\frac{9}{38}\frac{50}{13}=\frac{225}{247}$.

But as the question was about probability that the second watch is broken, the answer for this question is $P(A_2^c|B_1)=1-P(A_2|B_1)=\frac{22}{247}$.

Comment: Nice...............+1

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_1$ be the event that the first watch is broken,
$B_2$ be the event that the second watch is broken, and
$C_k$ be the event that the expert is correct about the $k$th watch.

Since the expert has an $80\%$ chance of being correct regardless of the condition of the watch, for each $k\in\mathbb N,\;P(C_k)=0.8.$ Thus, event $C_1$ is independent of event $B_1,$ and vice versa.

[image]

The required probability is \begin{align}&P(B_2|C_1B_1\cup\overline C_1\overline B_1)\\=&\frac{P(C_1B_1B_2,\overline C_1\overline B_1B_2)}{P(C_1B_1B_2,C_1B_1\overline B_2,\overline C_1\overline B_1B_2,\overline C_1\overline B_1\overline B_2)}\\=&\frac{0.8\times\frac2{20}\times\frac1{19}+0.2\times\frac{18}{20}\times\frac2{19}}{0.8\times\frac2{20}\times\frac1{19}+0.8\times\frac2{20}\times\frac{18}{19}+0.2\times\frac{18}{20}\times\frac2{19}+0.2\times\frac{18}{20}\times\frac{17}{19}}\\=&\frac{22}{247}.\end{align}